# Highcharts wrapper similar to Google visualization chartwrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, google-visualization

In [Google visualization ChartWrapper class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject), the code to draw a chart (bar chart, pie chart, etc) is as follows:

```
 wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            dataTable: dataTable.toJSON(),
            chartType: chartType,
            options: options
          });
          console.log("Wrapper: " + wrapper.toJSON());
          console.log(" ");
          wrapper.draw(result[0]);
```

I am curious if there's an equivalent way of doing this using Highcharts where instead of calling `new google.visualization.chartWrapper(...)`, we can just call something like `new highcharts.chartWrapper(...)`. The options can include the `container div id` where the chart will be drawn.

Even if there is no way to do, any suggestions how I should be go about doing something similar to this?

As far as I know, in `dataTable` I can specify my data series in JSON format. In `chartType`, I can specify bar, column, pie, etc. Based on the highcharts example I saw, I can even write a service that generates a HTML file on the server side as shown here -> http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/ and send back a response.

But what I don't know is how do I tell Highcharts to insert the chart right at `container id` specified in my options on the same page.

In this example, for instance, `wrapper` is just a json representation of the chart (which I can generate). What I am not sure is how do I convert that json representation to a highcharts map that gets inserted where I want on the same page.

Sorry, if this question seems complicated. I can clarify if you need additional information.

Comment: But in Highcharts when you create chart: `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options)` in options you can specify `chart.renderTo` for container. Also, all options are possible to set when creating chart. Then in `chart` variable you have access to all options, series, method etc.

Comment: Ok this is awesome to know. That's exactly what I was looking for. I tried digging on their website but couldn't find it. Let me keep looking. Thanks!

Comment: Found the documentation - http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options